# Codeigniter load color from database to css color selector

Tags: php, css, codeigniter, colors

I have an array which i pass into my views and contains all the needed data...

It also includes the user profile data with a link key and its color as value...

How can i pass it into the CSS in `color` selector in order to print the desired color for each user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not really rich in details, but you can do that using inline styles:

Use it in the head:

```
<style type="text/css">

#yourdiv{
   color: #<?php echo $color;?>
}

</style>
```

Or simply inline:

```
<div style="color:#<?php echo $color;?>"> Lorem ipsum </div>
```

Comment: That with the head works best as i see in other sites as well. thanks